# Does the wording make sense

Tags: word-usage

"A spark of hope flashed in his eyes."

I couldn't find any examples online. Just "a spark of hope in his eyes."

Comment: Is this about someone seeming (by their appearance, to an observer) to have had an idea, then the wording makes sense. Is this what you meant? You may also say that it 'flickered in his eyes'

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Light-related phenomena such as sparks, gleams, twinkles, etc, are often said to be figuratively visible in people's eyes. A spark can flash. Quite a normal expression.